# Replace string="" with string=null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I am trying to add a custom pattern to ReSharper (7.1) which will search for

```
string name = "";
```

and replace it with

```
string name = null;
```

I currently have this:

```
$string$ = "";
```

as searchpattern and replacepattern changes the "" to null so:

```
$string$ = null
```

$string$ is a placeholder to the expression of type System.String (and its derived classes)

This however does not show in Visual Studio. How can I fix this?

Comment: `design-patterns` tag is not suited for your question. Removed.

Comment: I wrote "patterns" which probably got changed to design-patterns, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a very good find and replace module, although the functionality is a bit hidden. It supports regular expressions so you can get creative :)

Please find below a trivial solution to your problem that should get you started:

[image: VS find and replace window]

Comment: The only problem with this, is that I want the search to be automated; which is why I chose for the resharper solution. But thanks for the suggestion!